# Блокировка папок

Tags: .htaccess

Закрыл доступ к папкам функцией `Options All -Indexes`, но мне нужен доступ к одной папке - `admin/`. Как сделать, чтобы только с моего ip можно было заходить в эту папку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - нужный ip

Добавлять, видимо, это нужно в `.htaccess` папки admin (точно про это не знаю). [Вот еще полезная статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/165701/).